# How can I know by code if the current sitecore instance is an XP or XM?

Tags: sitecore-api

I want to be able to determine in code if the current Sitecore instance is an XP or XM. As far I can see there is no direct way to do this, am I correct? If so, would it be advised to check if xdb is enabled in order to determine if the current instance is an XP or XM?

Kind regards,
Alex

Comment: See if this old [code](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2017/01/20/get-sitecore-system-info/) helps. May be you can get it from sitecore system info.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't depend on "Sitecore.Xdb.Configuration.XdbSettings.Enabled" setting. From (I believe) Sitecore 9.1 and onwards, Sitecore delivered XM packages and XP packages. Although XP can *run* in XM mode, it is still an XP instance. The XM package does not contain any specific XP assemblies, such as the Sitecore.Analytics assembly. This means that the following code probably doesn't work, as the xDB assembly isn't available at all in the XM package:

```
Sitecore.Xdb.Configuration.XdbSettings.Enabled
```

To overcome this, you could explicitly check if certain "XP specific assemblies" have been loaded or not, just by executing this logic:

```
var isXP = ContainsAssembly("Sitecore.Analytics");

private bool ContainsAssembly(string name)
    {
        bool assemblyLoaded = false;
        var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
        {
            var assemblyName = assembly.GetName();
            if (assemblyName.Name == name)
            {
                assemblyLoaded = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return assemblyLoaded;
    }
```

if the assembly is not in the app domain, you can be pretty sure that you are running an XM instance (and thus, XM mode). IF it *is* available, you can run extra checks, to see if you are running XP or XM *mode* in an XP *instance*

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think is if you are on Azure, you can use powershell to get the list of apps in your subscription plan. Once you have the list of apps, you can check if the app's name matches with the app names for marketing automation, xconnect, cortex etc. If matches are found, the instance is necessarily XP else XM. Below sample code can help to start with it -

```
function IsXpInstance($subscriptionId, $resourceGroupName) {   
Write-Host "Selecting subscription $($subscriptionId)..."
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
Write-Host "Selecting web apps..."    
$webApps = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
#Check for webapp names to be sure. They may have got updated with newer versions of Sitecore
$webApps | % {
    if ($_.Name.EndsWith("-ma-ops") -or $_.Name.EndsWith("-ma-rep") -or $_.Name.EndsWith("-xc-collect") `
        -or $_.Name.EndsWith("-xc-search") -or $_.Name.EndsWith("-xc-refdata")) {
        Write-Host -f Green " [XP]"
        break;
    }
}

}
```

If you want to achieve this in CSharp, you can make use of [Azure APIs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/list) to fetch the collection of webApps related to subscription and then do the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Code:**

`Sitecore.Xdb.Configuration.XdbSettings.Enabled`

True = xdb Enabled = XP is enabled

False = XP is disabled = XM only mode

**Using Config:**

In the file `Sitecore.Xdb.config` find `<setting name="Xdb.Enabled" value="true" />`

you can also check that setting in powershell.

I don't know the reason behind your question, but I have a feeling there must be a better approach than checking if it's `XP` or `XM`.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/enable-disable-the-xdb-and-the-tracker.html